# how do i add mysql database backend to golang web api application

Tags: go

I have webapi program which converts longer url a shorter url. i need add a backend mysql database.im having problem  integrating mysql code to my program. anysuggestions ?

```
// type short struct {
//  Longurl  string
//  Shorturl string
// }

// func GoDatabase(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request )
//  short :=  short{
//  Longurl path,
//      Shorturl    url,
//  }

var (
    linkList map[string]string
)

func init() {
    rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano())
}

func main() {
    linkList = map[string]string{}

    http.HandleFunc("/link", addLink)
    http.HandleFunc("/hpe/", getLink)
    http.HandleFunc("/", Home)

    ip := flag.String("i", "0.0.0.0", "")
    port := flag.String("p", "8080", "")
    flag.Parse()

    fmt.Printf("Listening on %s \n", net.JoinHostPort(*ip, *port))
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(net.JoinHostPort(*ip, *port), nil))
}

// Home - Home http request
func Home(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    fmt.Fprintf(w, "<h1>Tiny URL Program!<h1><br>\n")
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "text/html; charset=utf-8")
    io.WriteString(w, `
<form method="GET">
<label>Enter Url: </label>
<input type="text" name="ik" class="form-control" placeholder="Ex:http://google.com">
<button type="submit" formaction="/link">Submit</button>
</form>
</a>
</form>
<br>`)
    log.Println("Get Home")
    if r.URL.Path != "/" {
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusNotFound)
        return
    }
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
    var response string
    for shortLink, link := range linkList {
        response += fmt.Sprintf(" TinyLink: <a href=\"hpe/%s\">hpe/%s</a> \t\t OriginalURl: %s<br>", shortLink, shortLink, link)
    }

    fmt.Fprintf(w, response)
    return
}

// addLink - Add a link to the linkList and generate a shorter link
// Example: localhost:xxxx/hpe?a=https://google.com
func addLink(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    log.Println("Add Link")
    key, ok := r.URL.Query()["ik"]
    if ok {
        if !validLink(key[0]) {
            w.WriteHeader(http.StatusBadRequest)
            fmt.Fprintf(w, "Could not create shortlink need absolute path link.Ex: https://hpe.com/")
            return
        }
        log.Println(key)
        if _, ok := linkList[key[0]]; !ok {
            genString := randomString(5)
            linkList[genString] = key[0]
            w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "text/html")
            w.WriteHeader(http.StatusAccepted)

            linkString := fmt.Sprintf("<a href=\"hpe/%s\">hpe/%s</a>", genString, genString)
            fmt.Fprintf(w, "Added shortlink\n")
            fmt.Fprintf(w, linkString)
            return
        }
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusConflict)
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "Already have this link")
        return
    }

    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusBadRequest)
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Failed to add link")
    return
}

// validLink - check that the link we're creating a shortlink for is a absolute URL path
func validLink(link string) bool {
    r, err := regexp.Compile("^(http|https)://")
    if err != nil {
        return false
    }
    link = strings.TrimSpace(link)
    log.Printf("Checking for valid link: %s", link)
    // Check if string matches the regex
    if r.MatchString(link) {
        return true
    }
    return false
}

// getLink - Find link that matches the shortened link in the linkList
func getLink(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    path := r.URL.Path
    log.Println("Get Link:", path)
    pathArgs := strings.Split(path, "/")
    if len(pathArgs[2]) < 1 {
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusNotFound)
        http.Redirect(w, r, "127.0.0.1:8080", http.StatusTemporaryRedirect)
        return
    }
    log.Printf("Redirected to: %s", linkList[pathArgs[2]])
    http.Redirect(w, r, linkList[pathArgs[2]], http.StatusTemporaryRedirect)
    fmt.Printf("all %s", linkList)
    return
}

const characterBytes = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"

// randomStr - Create random short link
func randomString(n int) string {
    b := make([]byte, n)
    for i := range b {
        b[i] = characterBytes[rand.Intn(len(characterBytes))]
    }
    return string(b)
}
```

i tried following directions on tutorials but im having hard time printing out data on mysql. bassicaly im new to go and new mysql

```
func main() {
    db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "root:<yourMySQLdatabasepassword>@tcp(127.0.0.1:3306)/test")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }
    defer db.Close()
    fmt.Println("Success!")
}
```

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: nothing in database.